# Official reference doesn't include author

Tags: citations, citation-style

I want to cite an IEEE norm in a document. They provide several way to cite it on their website and in particular `bibTeX`. This is perfect because I use LaTeX.

However, the citation does not contain any author field. This raise a warning.

Should I keep this warning or modify the entry to avoid it? And in this case, what should I enter as author?

[Link to the norm page](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=4610935&filter%3DAND%28p_Publication_Number%3A4610933%29). In abstract, go to download citation.

For example bibTeX citation only:

```
 @ARTICLE{4610935,
journal={IEEE Std 754-2008},
title={IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic},
year={2008},
pages={1-70},
keywords={IEEE standards;floating point arithmetic;programming;IEEE standard;arithmetic formats;computer programming;decimal floating-point arithmetic;754-2008;NaN;arithmetic;binary;computer;decimal;exponent;floating-point;format;interchange;number;rounding;significand;subnormal},
doi={10.1109/IEEESTD.2008.4610935},
month={Aug},}
```

Comment: If the *citation provided by the publisher* doesn't include an entry for author, then it's likely there isn't meant to be one. What does your preferred citation style say about documents with no author?

Comment: @Andrew I use the IEEE bibliographic. Nothing about missing auteur. When I made my document I just have nothing printed as author nor a comma before the Title of the paper

Comment: @StephanKolassa the link where to download the document in the bibliography? Yes I can

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that the venue you want to publish in follows the [IEEE editorial style guide](http://www.ieee.org/documents/style_manual.pdf). On page 38, the guide shows how to reference standards:

> Basic Format:
>
> [1] *Title of Standard*, Standard number, date.
>
> Examples:
>
> [1] *IEEE Criteria for Class IE Electric Systems*, IEEE
>   Standard 308, 1969.
>
> [2] *Letter Symbols for Quantities*, ANSI Standard
>   Y10.5-1968.

So this is what the end result should look like. If this *is* your end result, you can disregard warnings.

However, I'd assume that BibTeX issues warnings about missing authors because it *expects* authors in the particular entry type you are using. You may need to recode your BibTeX file entry from, say, `@Article` to `@Techreport`. If you run into problems with (Bib)TeX, [tex.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) may be helpful.

Comment: I've no problem with BibTeX nor TeX. It's more about the style than the warning and if I should had an author or not. As your answer pointed out, I may just disregard this warning. Thank you `:-)`

Answer (score 5):

In my experience, the bibtex entries provided by many publishers are often quite bad, and IEEE is one of the worst offenders here. So it is quite common that one has to edit them before they become usable.

For this specific entry, the type "article" is clearly wrong, and the root of the problem.

Comment: As an example to support the claim, you could list [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=1333459), for which IEEE simply skips one of the authors in its metadata and the exported bibliography entries.